# Two questions about polynomials

Tags: polynomials

1.When $x^{99}+k$ is divided by $x+1$, the remainder is $1$.Find the value of k.Hence, find the remainder when $9^{99} $is divided by $10$.

2.Let $f(x)=x^2+ax+b$.If $f(x+1$) is divisible by $x+2$, and the remainder of $\frac{f(x-1)}{(x-2)}$ is $4$, find the values of $a$ and $b$.

For the first problem, I have calculated the value of k, which is 2, using the remainder theorem. But for finding the remainder of $9^{99}$, I have tried substituting $x$ as $8$ as $(8+1)$ is $9$, but then on the left side I get a huge number and a negative seven, which was wrong.I don't really understand how I can use $(x+1)$ and the remainder theorem into getting the remainder of such a large number.
For the second problem, I tried just substituting $(x+1)$ and $(x-2)$ into $f(x)$, but I am not sure whether I need to do some sort of thing where I have to write something like $f((x+1)-1)$ or $f((x-2)+2)$ to balance it out or anything? If this sounds messed out I apologize I don't really understand how this works.

Comment: $(x+1)$ divides $(x^{99} + 1).$  Therefore, when $x = 9$, $(9+1)$ divides $(9^{99} + 1).$  Therefore, when $(9^{99})$ is divided by $(9+1)$, the remainder is **what**?

Comment: For part 2, construct the polynomial that represents $f(x+1)$ and perform polynomial long division on it, dividing by $(x+2)$.  This will give you a single equation in $(a)$ and $(b)$.  Do the same polynomial long division on $f(x-1)$, dividing by $(x-2)$ and use the fact that this time there is a remainder of $4$  to create a 2nd equation involving $a$ and $b$.  Then solve for $a$ and $b$, using the two equations that you created.

Comment: I'm sorry but for the first part is it 9? How do I get there.Sorry I can't understand it.

Comment: Yes, since $(9+1)$ divides evenly into $(9^{99} + 1)$, then, when $9^{99}$ is divided by $(9+1)$ it must leave a remainder of $(9)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest approach to solve $1.$ is $$x^{99}+k\equiv (-1)^{99}+k=k-1\mod (x+1)$$ hence $k=2$. We also have $$9^{99}\equiv (-1)^{99}=-1\mod 10$$ hence the remainder is $9$

For $2.$ you can set $y=x+1$ , $z=x-1$. Then we have $$f(x+1)=f(y)=y^2+ay+b\equiv 1-a+b\mod (x+2)$$ and $$f(x-1)=f(z)=z^2+az+b\equiv a+b+1\mod (x-2)$$ This gives a system of two equations with $a$ and $b$ which you can easily solve.